# xpath going up to parent then back down to child

Tags: node.js, web, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

```
    <div class="classA">
        <label class="classB">
            <span>Referral Date</span>
        </label>
        <div>
            <input class="classC">
        </div>
     </div>
```

I'm using xpath to grab by 'Referral Date'. This is a requirement, as user will be passing this human readable label to me. I know how to get there:

```
    //div/label[@class="classB"]/span[text()="Referral Date"]
```

Now, I need to access input[@class="classC"] in order to click on it in my WebDriver Automation. Can I do something like this?

```
    //div/label[@class="classB"]/span[text()="Referral Date"]
    /parent::div/div/input[@class="classC"]
```

Well, this didn't work for me.

I also tried this without success:

```
    //div/label[@class="classB"]/span[text()="Referral Date"]
    /following-sibling::div/input[@class="classC"]
```

Didn't work, and I don't think it can because following sibling only refers to nodes within . Right?

Answer (score 2):

The parent of the span is label and not div.
Try these

```
//div/label[@class="classB"]/span[text()="Referral Date"]/ancestor::div[@class="classA"]//input[@class="classC"]

//div/label[@class="classB"]/span[text()="Referral Date"]/parent::label/parent::div//input[@class="classC"]

//div/label[@class="classB"]/span[text()="Referral Date"]/parent::label/following-sibling::div/input[@class="classC"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below `XPath` to match required `input`:

```
//div/label[@class="classB"]/span[text()="Referral Date"]/following::input[@class="classC"]
```